# SVN disallowing editing via externals

Tags: svn

In SVN, is there a way to disable commits of changes made to file that exists locally as an external?

I want to force my users to checkout the actual file, make changes, and commit there. Then they can test each of the known subscribed projects of that file to make sure they didn't break something.

Comment: One way of solving this is to have the "template" file that must be renamed in working copy in order to be used. Without renaming the file the project will not run, so user is forced to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. I have a [Precommit Hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that may work.

Unfortunately, when you edit an external directory, `svnlook` doesn't have a way to distinguish whether or not it's an external. I believe earlier versions of SVN didn't let you directly edit externals because I remember that seemed to be the default behavior (I'm talking about 1.2 and 1.3 here).

However, you could use this hook to prevent users from editing files under directories that look like externals.

Assume that you have a project `http://svn.vegicorp.com/repo/trunk/common` that's used in `http://svn.vegicorp.com/repo/trunk/foomaster` and `http://svn.vegicorp.com/repo/trunk/barmaster`. The externals are under the directory `common` under these projects:

```
[file You cannot edit an external directory. Please checkout http://svn.vegicorp.com/repo/trunk/common to edit that file]
file = /trunk/*/common
access = read-only
users = @ALL

[file You cannot edit an external directory. Please checkout http://svn.vegicorp.com/repo/trunk/common to edit that file]
file = /branches/*/*/common
access = read-only
users = @ALL

[file Good for you! You checked out http://svn.vegicorp.com/repo/trunk/common ]
file = /trunk/common/**
access = read-write
users = @ALL

[file Good for you! You checked out http://svn.vegicorp.com/repo/trunk/common ]
file = /branches/*/common/**
access = read-write
users = @ALL
```